# Where to call database in method on model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

In a MVC app with Entity Framework 4 I am trying to add some more code to a `Schedule` model. Right now a method on this model is called from code to get a list of dates that are not in the weekend. The model is called from controllers in this way `var freeDates = Schedule.GetDatesNextThirtyDays()`.

To do the above, no database call is necessary. I want to add a method that checks if the date is a "structural free day" (free every year). This method needs to make a database call, since the free days will be stored in the `StructuralFreeDay` model consisting of `string DayMonth` <sup>(maybe I will use DateTime and ignore year part, have to watch out for leap years though - this is another problem)</sup> and `string Reason`.

```
// get a list of dates (within the next 30 days) that are eligible for duty
public static ICollection<DateTime> GetDatesNextThirtyDays()
{
    ICollection<DateTime> plannableDates = new List<DateTime>();
    var date = DateTime.Today;

    for (var i = 0; i < 29; i++)
    {
        if (!IsWeekend(date) && !IsStructuralFreeDay(date)) // <= The new method.
        {
            plannableDates.Add(date);
        }
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }
    return plannableDates;
}

// return true if day is not saturday, sunday
public static bool IsWeekend(DateTime day)
{
    return day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || day.Date.DayOfWeek == 
         DayOfWeek.Sunday;
}
```

I prefer to add the new method `bool IsStructuralFreeDate` with the database call in the `GetDatesNextThirtyDays` method, since that is where it is used. Is it okay to instantiate a `DbContext` and make a call to the database in the model? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question user2609980 (great name also ;)). As with any meta question like this it depends as much on your environment, timeline and internal standards as it does any presumed "best practice".

For what it's worth, my instinct would be to place the function in the controller. To me models should be as close to property-bags as possible. If there's logic to be had in a model then it should be focused on transforming existing data in the model via an additional read-only parameter. I also find it cleaner to keep all UOW management to the controller where DI can be used to provide the appropriate UOW instance whether called from the site or from tests.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great answer Rob (great name as well). I am going for a call in the controller as well (since we are creating a fake database context in our unit tests and inject them in controllers I will keep the logic there), and decided to rename the method to `GetNonWeekendDaysNextThirtyDays`. Then I create a `var freeDates` by removing the structural free days from the returned list of `GetNonWeekendDaysNextThirtyDays` method.

Comment: Model = whole business logic. It's not true that your model = simple property bag. You somewhat misunderstood the whole concept of MVC...

Comment: @walther Hi, should we make database calls from controller, or place them in model? My preferred solution would be to make a side class with a repository where all database calls are made. But where to call the methods from this repository? From controllers?

Comment: Indeed Walther. In MVC the model would be responsible for data and logic. I would generally relegate data retrieval to a separate repository at which point, in my opinion, that data could be bound to the model in the controller. Are there testing benefits to having the controller call into the model to have the model retrieve and bind it's own data?

Comment: I think your controller shouldn't know a thing about how do you retrieve your data, where do they come from originally nor contain some dandy functions that actually belong to BL. Controller is part of the presentation layer and as such should be only used as a means of responding to requests (somehow parse the data from the user, call some function from business logic and construct a meaningful response back to the calling client).

Comment: @user2609980, if you want to get some data to controller, you should use some other class (repository for instance) and use that to communicate with the database layer. Controller shouldn't know the details. If you need to use some mediator class that will further play with the request, call repository etc., that's up to you, your habits and the complexity of the website. Whatever you end up doing, just stick with it (at least until you finish the site). It's not really that important what path you take, as long as you keep it consistent across the whole application/website.